# Do I need to use copy when working on the same dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I was wondering if the copy method are useful in the following cases:

```
df_av = df_av[['plan_name', 'ADO_ver', 'ADO_incr']].copy()
df_av = df_av.dropna(how='all').copy()
```

Are these lines equivalent to:

```
df_av = df_av[['plan_name', 'ADO_ver', 'ADO_incr']]
df_av = df_av.dropna(how='all')
```

Comment: Hi, they are equivalent in the sense that each line, with or without copy, creates a new object and reassigns it to the same variable. The use of copy only makes sense if you intend to *mutate* `df_av` after assigning it to another variable (other_df = df_av).